# change order of labels being printed in QuickReport Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, quickreports

I'm looking for advice.

We have Delphi program with a complicated QuickReport.
There are TQrLabel and TQrExpr, each with its own OnPrint event.

As for now, the TQRLabel is being printed first and then the TQRExpr.
But I need to determine what to print in TQRLabel based on value of TQRExpr.

Is there any way to change the printing order?

Or call TQrLabel.OnPrint event programmatically after TQRExpr.OnPrint called?
(The TQrLabel parent is a TQrGroup, so I cannot call printBand)

It is Delphi 5 with QR 3.0.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wild guess: right click label ➔ Control ➔ Bring to front / Send to back. Controls at the back are probably printed first.

Comment: Instead of changing the printing order, change what the label contains. That is after-all under your control.

Comment: @FreddieBell I still need to show that information on the same position in report

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that if I call QuickReport.Prepare, it will calculate the QRExpr Values.
Now I call QuickReport.Print, I can print value in QRLabel based on QRExpr value.